# Is it true what developer could use haxe both for frontend and backend in production development - source needed

Tags: haxe

Is it true what developer could use `haxe` both for frontend (web and desktop) and backend in production development - source needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is true.

Haxe can transpile to a wide range of languages, such as PHP, Javascript, C++, Java, Python ... So you're able to develop in Haxe and target the desired platform (language).

Couple of examples for you - take a look at the Haxe web-site - http://haxe.org/use-cases/ for a variety of Use Cases.

Haxe / nodejs - http://matthijskamstra.github.io/haxenode/

Also wanted to add you can use mod_neko - http://old.haxe.org/doc/build/mod_neko as an apache module to embed the neko virtual machine - so this means you can run your haxe programs server-side.

Comment: It's good to mention that the Haxe website is build with Haxe. This has a front and a backend written in Haxe.

Answer (score 3):

HxDom (https://github.com/Blank101/haxe-dom) is very interesting. I'm using it in a current project for building/populating DOM structures on the server (neko) and using/manipulating that data in the browser (js). It's the most easy-to-use way of working with the DOM (server and client) that i've tried - no need to adopt a new workflow/toolset (à la React and other solutions).

Comment: Why not to add your second answer to first?

Comment: I didn't realize that they should drift apart because of voting... Will edit this one slightly so that it stands for itself.